# Pointers aren't being transferred to allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management, environment-variables

I have a school assignment, and everything works just fine except for one part, which I cannot figure out. The following is the snippet of code where my issue is occurring:

```
    //something goes wrong here, wont copy over
    puts("bravo");
    //add to end of the list
    int size_list = sizeof(environ);
    //char** tmp_ptr = ( char** )calloc( size_list + 1, ( size_list + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
    char** tmp_ptr = ( char** ) malloc ( ( size_list + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
    int k;
    for ( k = 0; k < size_list; ++k )
    {
        tmp_ptr[k] = environ[k];
        //memcpy(tmp_ptr[k],environ[k],sizeof(environ[k]));
    }
    //char** tmp_ptr= (char**)realloc(*environ, size_list+2);
    environ = tmp_ptr;
    environ[size_list] = (char*)malloc(len_string+1);
    strcpy(environ[size_list],full_string);
    return 1;
```

You can ignore the "bravo", it was for me to locate where the problem was occurring. I am trying to get environ to have the new list of variables, but when I set it equal to tmp_ptr, it is empty. I'm pretty sure that the values are getting copied over, but I do not know what is wrong. 
Does the data in tmp_ptr get deleted when the function ends? Is that a possible explanation? How can I properly allocate and copy over the memory. I tried using realloc, but that gave me invalid pointer errors, so I am relying on calloc or malloc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a full C program that is compilable that shows your issue - there is too much info missing eg what is environ? Oh and sizeof returns an unsigned number

Comment: Note that `t = strdup(s)` is a quicker alternative to `t = malloc(strlen(s)+1); strcpy(t, s)`.

Comment: the full C code is like 250 lines. extern char **environ; is the environmental variable on unix/linux systems. size_list is just sizeof(environ) and len_string is the length of full_string which is a cstring or rather another environmental variable that I want to add to the end of environ.

Comment: @nneonneo, keep in mind that strdup isn't ISO C, it's POSIX. There's a good chance it's available however.

Comment: I do want to ask: what do you mean by "it becomes empty"? Does your entire environment get wiped out, or only the string you set?

Comment: Sorry about the "it becomes empty". Twas a poor choice of vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

`environ`'s length isn't `sizeof(environ)`, since `environ` is a `char **` (and thus `sizeof(environ)` is 4 or 8 depending on your platform). What you're doing is effectively wiping out most of `environ` because you only copy the first few entries.

To find out how many entries are in `environ`, do

```
int cnt = 0;
char **envp = environ;
while(*envp++) cnt++;
```

I should also note a problem with the approach: since `environ` is a `NULL`-terminated string array (not to be confused with 'null-terminated string'), you have to *replace* the `NULL` at the end with your own entry, then add a new `NULL` after your new entry. Currently, your code (if it calculated the size correctly) would have added your entry after the `NULL`, and would have not been visible to the program.

Side note: messing with `environ` this way is definitely not recommended. Use `getenv`/`setenv` instead; if you need to mass-set the environment, try using `execve` instead. (So, in your case, you can simply `setenv("varname", "varvalue", 1)` to add `varname=varvalue` to the environment (and replace an existing mapping to `varname` if it is already set).

Comment: `environ` is a standard libc pointer to the environment. See http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/environ.5.asp.

Comment: I could accept that as long as the OP does not have a variable with the same name

Comment: He's certainly *using* it like `environ`. Even if it's not "the" `environ`, it's a pointer of some sort (since  `tmp_ptr[k] = environ[k]` and `environ = tmp_ptr` work).

Comment: Probably - but I've seen newbies do some amazing things - as soon as they clarify - I shall remove the downvote :-)

Comment: "extern char **environ; is the environmental variable on unix/linux systems.". happy now? :P

Comment: No - now what is it `#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   float *environ;
   return 0;
}
`

Comment: @AdrianCornish: If you think OP is being stupid and redefining `environ`, you should add it as an answer. Otherwise, it is not meaningful to downvote for giving a best-effort guess based on the evidence.

Comment: 'now what is it' -- totally irrelevant. You're trolling good answers, Adrian. Stop it.

Comment: I've spent many years on comp.lang.c and comp.lang.c++ - if you do not have all the facts it is hard to answer for certain - yes you can guess and yes you may be correct - but for perpetuity guessing is not good. It probably is - you could simple add a line to the answer that says 'I assume that environ is...' - but a probably good answer is not fact until important things like environ's def is confirmed. Maybe today's generation do not care for exact answers - but compilers do

Comment: This isn't `comp.lang.c`. I don't want to argue the point further -- if you want to stick me with a downvote, then so be it.

Comment: Why not just improve the answer with 'assume environ is...' - that is all you need. PS compilers are more pedantic than I :-) - all I was trying to do was make you answer perfect rather than an educated guess

Comment: We had a constraint not to use setenv, or any of those env functions. We have to design our own.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: OK, then why didn't you just tell me to improve the answer in that way, rather than challenging it? At this point, it doesn't matter since OP has stated what `environ` is.

Comment: @MichaelM: Ah, I see. You should add this information to the question so that it is clear what you are doing.

Comment: @nneonneo Point taken and accepted - I should have - at the early stage it was just a comment which I could have phrased better and more helpfully :-)

Answer (score 3):

`environ` is a *pointer,* meaning that `sizeof(environ)` is not the number of items in that array. Rather, it's the size of the pointer, probably four or eight in your case.

If `environ` is the same sort of structure as `argv` (an array of character pointers where the last one is a null pointer), you will need to determine its size by walking through the array until you find NULL.

Something like (untested, but the idea is sound):

```
char **envPtr = environ;
int size_list = 0;            // probably should be size_t
while (*envPtr != NULL) {
    envPtr++;
    size_list++;
}
```

You can see the effect in this complete program (with a few changes to get around some other bugs):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define full_string "xyzzy=plugh"
#define len_string strlen(full_string)

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int k, size_list = sizeof(environ);
    char **tmp_ptr = malloc ((size_list + 1) * sizeof ( char*));

    for (k = 0; k < size_list; ++k) printf ("[%s]\n", environ[k]);
    for (k = 0; k < size_list; ++k) tmp_ptr[k] = environ[k];
    tmp_ptr[size_list] = NULL;

    environ = tmp_ptr;
    environ[size_list] = malloc (len_string + 1);
    strcpy(environ[size_list],full_string);

    printf ("=====\n");
    for (k = 0; k <= size_list; ++k) printf ("[%s]\n", environ[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs only four of my environment variables because I have four-byte pointers:

```
[ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-pax]
[SSH_AGENT_PID=1978]
[GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/seahorse-tNDhG9/S.gpg-agent:2005:1]
[TERM=xterm]
=====
[ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-pax]
[SSH_AGENT_PID=1978]
[GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/seahorse-tNDhG9/S.gpg-agent:2005:1]
[TERM=xterm]
[xyzzy=plugh]
```

Changing the code to correctly determine the size of the environment:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define full_string "xyzzy=plugh"
#define len_string strlen(full_string)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int k, size_list = 0;
    char **envPtr = environ;
    while (*envPtr != NULL) {
        envPtr++;
        size_list++;
    }
    char **tmp_ptr = malloc ((size_list + 1) * sizeof (char*));

    for (k = 0; k < size_list; ++k) printf ("[%s]\n", environ[k]);
    for (k = 0; k < size_list; ++k) tmp_ptr[k] = environ[k];
    tmp_ptr[size_list] = NULL;

    environ = tmp_ptr;
    environ[size_list] = malloc (len_string + 1);
    strcpy(environ[size_list],full_string);

    printf ("=====\n");
    for (k = 0; k <= size_list; ++k) printf ("[%s]\n", environ[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

gives me the lot:

```
[ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-pax]
[SSH_AGENT_PID=1978]
[GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/seahorse-tNDhG9/S.gpg-agent:2005:1]
[TERM=xterm]
[SHELL=/bin/bash]
[GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/pax/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2]
[WINDOWID=62914564]
[GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-RADe9n]
[GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module]
[USER=pax]
:
[XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm3/auth-for-pax-AO1dYc/database]
[_=./testprog]
=====
[ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-pax]
[SSH_AGENT_PID=1978]
[GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/seahorse-tNDhG9/S.gpg-agent:2005:1]
[TERM=xterm]
[SHELL=/bin/bash]
[GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/pax/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2]
[WINDOWID=62914564]
[GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-RADe9n]
[GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module]
[USER=pax]
:
[XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm3/auth-for-pax-AO1dYc/database]
[_=./testprog]
[xyzzy=plugh]
```

---

For what it's worth, your code had the following problems:

- The incorrect calculation of the environment size, obviously.
- Casting the return value from `malloc` - this is ill-advised in C since it can cause code problems to be hidden from you.
- Not setting the final element of the new list to NULL.
- Not checking for out-of-memory conditions.

All these except the last are fixed in my final code sample above.

Comment: @Adrian, the fact that OP is assigning `tmp_ptr` to `environ`, and the fact that `environ` is exactly that in a number of systems, makes it a safe bet it's the same type. In any case, I stated **If enviriron is the same ...**. Perhaps you might consider a remedial reading course :-)

Comment: Then, he should have at least seen 4 or 8 strings. but he sees nothing!

Comment: I don't think that would be sufficient.

Comment: @Reza, I've punched in the code (though I had to add a couple of things to get it to compile) and I do indeed see four strings. My fix also changes that so that the entire environment is seen. See the answer update for details.